# Simple thread pool in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

Could anyone point me to a sample implementation of a thread pool in C++, please?  I'm looking for a very basic one without too much complexity, which would be suitable for a beginner in threading to study.

Comment: We can't do much but google "C++ threadpool" for you. Maybe you should rather try and implement a threadpool by yourself and come back with specific questions when facing difficulties.

Comment: thanks for that..in a thread pool should i first create some x threads and then assign it to somework whenever we have a work...in that case how would i just create a thread?

Comment: When you say a "very basic one," what do you mean? If you are new to C++ or programming, there will be no such thing. I would look into simple multi-threading first, and move your way into examples or look through how other libraries (e.g. BOOST or threadpool library) do it if you wish to implement your own.

Answer (score 4):

Look at Intel's [Thread Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).  I don't know how well that library meets your "simple" criteria, but it seems to be very well thought-out and thorough.  I would think that it would be worth the effort to learn if you want to do threading in C++.

[Boost](http://boost.org) also has some threading facilities.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth to check out Qt's QThreadPool implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good one : [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) its built uppon boost so its cross platform and everything , very easy to use as well

Answer (score 0):

in his book Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development, Jeff Langr walks thru a threadpool implementation. It's a busy wait implementation. I've modified it further here https://github.com/spakai/threadpool_future to support things such as signal-wait and futures.