# A simple thread's pool in C++ with thread priorities

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [threadpool in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179316/threadpool-in-c)

I need to write my own or use already written thread's pool in C++ with priorities. Boost threadpool is too complicated. Please, advice me one.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179316/threadpool-in-c

Comment: Hmm, let me think. The BOOST one (which is tried and tested by the way) is too complicated for you, yet you're quite comfortable with writing your own, despite the fact it will have a substantial number of bugs in it and take you a not-inconsiderable amount of time and effort. Did the whole concept of reusable software just pass you by? :-)

Comment: Well, the boost one is quite slow, i think... and not so easy in using... When i'm talking about writing my own, i don't mean writing my own from the beginning, but maybe using some other components already written by somebody else.

Comment: Rest assured that the cost of writing your will be far higher than the cost of learning how to use any given implementation. Do not underestimate the value of using software that was tested and used by many others over a long time, and thus is much more stable than anything you could hope to implement on your own in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: While others have pointed out it's not a very practical approach, there's nothing wrong with asking for implementation advice here, even if only from curiousity.  That said, Google can turn up existing libraries in seconds (e.g. http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) - you might at least list some that seem to fit your needs and ask for recommendations, or failing that specify your portability requirements, or spend a few hours writing a threadpool then ask for specific implementation help if stuck....

Answer (score 0):

If you have a basic understanding of how to write a simple threadpool with `std::queue`, change `std::queue` to `std::priority_queue` and you will get a threadpool with priorities